# How do I 3-way merge using TortoiseHg 2.0.3 and Beyond Compare 3.2.4

Tags: tortoisehg, beyondcompare3, tortoisehg-2.0, 3-way-merge

I can configure TortoiseHg to launch Beyond Compare 3 when a 3-way merge is needed, but I haven't been able to get it to show the names and versions of the files being compared. It displays the names and versions of files when doing a 2-way file compare. Does anyone know how to configure it properly? KDiff3 has the same problem.

Following the direections at the BC support site (http://www.scootersoftware.com/support.php?zz=kb_vcs) sets BC3 as the 3-way merge tool, but it doesn't show the filenames or versions.

[Using mercurial and beyond compare 3(bc3) as the diff tool? help needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323521/using-mercurial-and-beyond-compare-3bc3-as-the-diff-tool-help-needed) almost answers the question. It works for 2-way compares, but not for 3-way merges. Can anyone tell me how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

I have TortoiseHG 2.0.2 and Beyond Compare 3.1.11 when doing a 3 way merge its typically the base in the middle and the 2 differences on either side.  The way I usually tell them apart is the content.  What I did not like about the way It does a 3 way merge is you have to sometimes chose one side over the other (the blue or the pink) and can not go with both (containing both branches).  Example: If I put a new function in the bottom of my class in 2 branches and merged them on top of the base beyond compare will make me chose one or the other function and I can not have both.

Comment: You can have changes from both sides. Use Ctrl+B to Take Left then Right, or Shift+Ctrl+B to Take Right then Left. See the Edit menu for the options. Moreover the text in the Merge pane can be fully edited.