# hg merge with BeyondCompare - how to mark as merged

Tags: mercurial, beyondcompare3

How can I use BeyondCompare3 to mark a merge as resolved. In the bottom pane I select the filename and save then exit however hg always shows me the merge as failing?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using mercurial and beyond compare 3(bc3) as the diff tool? help needed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/323521/using-mercurial-and-beyond-compare-3bc3-as-the-diff-tool-help-needed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file should be automatically marked as resolved once you saved output in the bottom pane. (You don't need to select filename as it should be point to the right place from the beginning.)

Any chance you might have misconfigured BeyondCompare as a merge tool? Here is a relevant part of the configuration file which always work for me:

```
[ui]
merge = beyondcompare3

[extensions]
extdiff=

[extdiff]
md.beyondcompare3 = c:\Program Files (x86)\Beyond Compare 3\BCompare.exe
opts.beyondcompare3 = /leftreadonly

[merge-tools]
; Windows version of BeyondCompare 3
beyondcompare3.priority=-1
beyondcompare3.args=$local $other $base /mergeoutput=$output /ro /lefttitle=local /centertitle=base /righttitle=other /outputtitle=merged /automerge /reviewconflicts /solo
beyondcompare3.premerge=False
beyondcompare3.regkey=Software\Scooter Software\Beyond Compare 3
beyondcompare3.regname=ExePath
beyondcompare3.gui=True
beyondcompare3.diffargs=/lro /lefttitle='$plabel1' /righttitle='$clabel' /solo /expandall $parent $child
beyondcompare3.diff3args=$parent1 $parent2 $child /lefttitle='$plabel1' /centertitle='$clabel' /righttitle='$plabel2' /solo /ro
beyondcompare3.dirdiff=True
beyondcompare3.binary=True

[tortoisehg]
vdiff = beyondcompare3
```

Comment: I did have the wrong config. There are 101 different examples with different settings. This fixed it. Thanks muchly +1